# Picture box Visibility does not change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application in which I send a simple Email to test ID. The problem is the visibility property of picturebox does not change. 
Can anyone suggest a simple solution?

**My button Click**

```
private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        pbLoad.Visible = true;
        sendemail();
        pbLoad.Visible = false;

        MessageBox.Show("Mail send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Send Email Function**

```
   public void sendemail()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 100000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
          "myID@gmail.com", "mypassword");
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(txt_to.Text);
        msg.From = new MailAddress("myID@gmail.com");
        msg.Subject = txt_sub.Text;
        msg.Body = txt_msg.Text;

        //  Attachment data = new Attachment(txt_attach.Text);
        //     msg.Attachments.Add(data);
        // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: pbLoad is a gif Image

Comment: do you want to use loading images

Comment: yes. actually its a animated loading Gif Image inside a picture box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not giving the main thread chance to render it. Your main thread is busy in sending the mail. You need to send the mail in another thread. Prefer `Task.Run`.

Use [Async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) feature and call `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync` which doesn't block the calling thread. So that UI thread will have a time to render the picture box.

Your method should be something like this:

```
private async void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        pbLoad.Visible = true;
        await SendEmailAsync();
        pbLoad.Visible = false;

        MessageBox.Show("Mail send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public Task SendEmailAsync()
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    client.Port = 587;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Timeout = 100000;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
      "myID@gmail.com", "mypassword");
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add(txt_to.Text);
    msg.From = new MailAddress("myID@gmail.com");
    msg.Subject = txt_sub.Text;
    msg.Body = txt_msg.Text;

    //  Attachment data = new Attachment(txt_attach.Text);
    //     msg.Attachments.Add(data);
    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return client.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain a lil bit more i m new to Winforms

Comment: @user3859356 Which version of .net you use?

Comment: regarding whatto write inside sendEmailSync

Comment: Updated my answer, that should work. Learn more about async/await in the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

Using Threading concept

```
private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            pbLoad.Visible = true;

            Thread t=New Thread(sendemail);
            t.start();

         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void sendemail()
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
              "myID@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(txt_to.Text);
            msg.From = new MailAddress("myID@gmail.com");
            msg.Subject = txt_sub.Text;
            msg.Body = txt_msg.Text;

            //  Attachment data = new Attachment(txt_attach.Text);
            //     msg.Attachments.Add(data);
            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            client.Send(msg);

           this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Finished))

        }
    }

Private Void Finished() 

{

 pbLoad.Visible = false;
 MessageBox.Show("Mail send");

}
```